# Getting browsermob/proxy (LoadError) in windows 7

Tags: ruby, selenium, proxy, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to run Browsermob proxy tool using selenium cucumber with a ruby in windows 7 but am facing with browsermob/proxy (LoadError) while importing browsermob/proxy libriary. I installed all required gems. could someone help me with this issue

This is my code:

`require 'browsermob/proxy'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec/expectations'
include RSpec::Matchers`

This is the error message:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
```

`require': cannot load such file -- browsermob/proxy (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:55:in 'require'
        from bandwidth_limit.rb:3:in '<main>'`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Install Browsermob proxy using gem install. give below command in command prompt

```
gem install browsermob-proxy
```